# Accents stored in Redis not being readable

Tags: redis

Working with Redis 2.10 using redis-cli on Linux, I am faced with a problem regarding accents.

If I execute the command :

```
set "string" "à"
```

I get `\xc3\xa0`, it seems each converted accent begin with `\xc3`.

How do I get my original string back?

Comment: OK I checked all my previous questions and it's effectively an UTF8 problem...

Comment: It's usually not much of a problem, though. Do you absolutely have to use a 1-byte-per-char encoding?

Comment: @kozher did you find out how to read those string back with the accents ?

Answer (score 39):

Try using

```
redis-cli --raw
```

It solved problem for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works within the CLI, but not if you directly run the command all in one line (such as: redis-cli --raw HGETALL myHashKey > mqResult.txt).

Answer (score 9):

"\xc3\xa0" is just Unicode "à" in UTF-8 encoding.  Just decode the string and you're done...

Answer (score 2):

```
<you string>.encode("utf-8")
```

when you need get the string do

```
<you string>.decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to spec the version of Redis and more importantly the client you are using.

If you are using a telnet client, [the problem may be your client](http://groups.google.com/group/linuxusersgroup/browse_thread/thread/b34f4026cdcb81ea/9151dbd89772ae69).  Redis supports arbitrary bytes for values and UTF-8 is not a problem at all (if your client is properly converting the entered glyphs to the associated byte sequence.)

Comment: I am using the client redis-cli (Redis 2.10) with linux or make my insertions with Java.