# Redis encoding on Windows

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8, redis, redis-cli

I've been testing Redis on Windows from a PowerShell console and I cannot get keys with locale diacritic signes (values are in French). I've just discovered *--raw* option from another SOF question [how-to-save-and-retrieve-string-with-accents-in-redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963372/how-to-save-and-retrieve-string-with-accents-in-redis), but it doesn't help.

[redis-2.8.17, PoSH-4 native console or [cmder](https://bliker.github.io/cmder/), win-8.1]

```
PS4 C:\temp> redis-cli.exe set t "téléphone"
OK
PS4 C:\temp> redis-cli.exe get t
"t\xe9l\xe9phone"
PS4 C:\temp> redis-cli.exe --raw set t "téléphone"
OK
PS4 C:\temp> redis-cli.exe get t
"t\xe9l\xe9phone"
PS4 C:\temp> redis-cli.exe --raw get t
tÚlÚphone
```

The behaviour is slightly different from Redis REPL :

```
PS4 C:\temp> redis-cli.exe
127.0.0.1:6379>
127.0.0.1:6379> get t
"t\xe9l\xe9phone"
```

but

```
PS4 C:\temp> redis-cli.exe --raw
127.0.0.1:6379> get t
tÚlÚphone
127.0.0.1:6379> set t "tﾂlﾂphone"  # yes, strange echo of my keys
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get t              # but right output
téléphone
```

So what encoding should I use to set and get all accents?  If not possible, how to encode correctly "t\xe9l\xe9phone" from PowerShell?  Is it plain Unicode?