# UTF-8 in redis-cli

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I'm trying to show UTF-8 content in redis-cli.

I've tried this solution:

```
redis-cli --raw
```

which was suggested here:
[Redis - problem with accents (UTF-8 encoding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731450/redis-problem-with-accents-utf-8-encoding)

But this is what i'm getting:
╫₧╫ù╫ò╫û ╫Ö╫¿╫ò╫⌐╫£╫Ö╫¥

Can someone assist ?

Comment: Is it linux or windows?

Answer (score -1):

try command 
chcp 65001

in cmd window

Comment: Nobody should blindly run some command without knowing what it does. You should edit your answer to explain what it is and what it's going to do. Not that this is being sought anymore (the question was posted in 2015)...

Comment: Running any command is your responsibility. OK, than we should delete all question older than you like, because nobody won't have this problem anymore.