# How to get Unicode string from redis cache using StackExchange.Redis in c#?

Tags: c#, encoding, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using **StackExchange.Redis** library to work with redis. I have set Unicode string value as below.

```
db.StringSet(key,"धन्यवाद");
```

And I am trying to get Unicode string using

```
db.StringGet(key);
```

But getting ????? instead of Unicode string. Redis stores Unicode string value in below format.

```
\xe0\xa4\xa7\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa4\xb5\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xa6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis - problem with accents (UTF-8 encoding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731450/redis-problem-with-accents-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: @Nico getting (error) ERR unknown command '--raw' on redis cli. Have you tried this?!!!

Comment: I test your code, it works fine and i can get the right string  and cmd like 'redis-cli --raw mget key'  works fine on my pc, too. I think its a enviroment problem, what is your redis version? If it still does not work, just check the second answer, decode that string.

Answer (score 0):

`RedisValue` has an implicit cast operator of type string. It encodes it as an `UTF-8` byte array before sending it. If you have your string in `Unicode` you should obtain the bytes by yourself.

```
byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);
db.StringSet(key, data);
...
data = db.StringGet(key);
value = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
```